# JQuery not working with same name of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, razor

In Razor View of I have written the html code for table

```
<tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.TodaysVM)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@item.OrderId</td>
                                        <td>@item.WorkOrderType</td>
                                        <td>@item.CustomerId</td>
                                        <td>@item.CustomerName</td>
                                        <td>@item.AppointmentDate</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="addCustomActivity" data-id=@item.OrderId>Add Custom Activity</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
```

Now Let's say when click the button Add Custom Activity I need to alert the value of respective @item.orderID there might be a multiple row in the table and each row contains the button.
My JQuery Code is :

```
 $("#addCustomActivity").click(function () {
                alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
            });
```

I works fine but the problem is the it only works for first row of the table. the button dosen't works for second row. How I can fix this so that the button works for every row?

Comment: An ID must be unique.

Comment: *"same name"* - none of your elements has a `name` attribute.  `id` is not the same as `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ID` must always be unique, If you have multiple elements with the same id it will always select the first element it finds with that id

Change `class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="addCustomActivity"` to `class="btn btn-primary btn-sm addCustomActivity"`

Then you can use:

```
$(".addCustomActivity").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

*NOTE*

Your title `JQuery not working with same name of multiple elements` would actually work, if you had `name="addCustomActivity"` and then your `jQuery` code would look like:

```
$("button[name=addCustomActivity]").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```